# Dijkstras Algorithm with Bounded Integer Edge Weights

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs

I don't really understand how we can use the fact that the edge weights are integers in the range [1, 2, ... , C] in order to speed up the computation of Dijkstra's algorithm. I read [this lecture](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/rec/rec16.pdf) but I still don't really get it. I understand why we make an array of size |V|C + 1 holding buckets where we put nodes with length **i** in bucket **i**. But from that point on I can't really wrap my head around how it'd help us solve it any faster.

I suppose we start off with putting the startnode s in the 0:th bucket and then putting its neighbors in their respective buckets, but that's just the normal algorithm. How does it change from there?

Comment: related [Dijkstra's algorithm for edge weights in range 0, …, W](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19252) and [Modifying Dijkstra's algorithm for edge weights drawn from range $[1,…,K]$](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6797)